# How can i make a tcp server without a client

Tags: python, tcp, server

How can i make it so when someone connects to port 8080 they see the login screen and password instead of a client joining, for example i opened putty up and i clicked protocol "RAW" i put the I.P of 208.67.1.1 <- example I.P and port 8080 nothing shows but i don't get a connection refused.
Here's my code:

```
import sys
import time
from socket import *

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

USER = "Haze"
PASS = "Myinternet202"
HOST = "0.0.0.0"
PORT = 8080
sock.bind((HOST, PORT))
sock.listen(1)

nickname = raw_input("Nickname: ")
if nickname == "%s" % (USER):
    credentialsU = True
else:
    credentialsU = False

if credentialsU == False:
    print '----------------------------------------'
    print '-          INVALID CREDENTIALS         -'
    print '----------------------------------------'
    time.sleep(5)
    sys.exit(1)

password = raw_input("Password: ")
if password == "%s" % (PASS):
    credentialsP = True
else:
    credentialsP = False

if credentialsP == False: 
    print '----------------------------------------'
    print '-          INVALID CREDENTIALS         -'
    print '----------------------------------------'
    time.sleep(5)
    sys.exit(1)

if credentialsU == True and credentialsP == True:
while True:
    main = raw_input("> ")

    logs = open("logs.txt", "a")
    logs.write("" + nickname + " -> " + main + "\r\n")
    logs.close()
```

Comment: What an annoying feature it would be if `raw_input()` and `print` searched the local namespace for variables bound to sockets, picked one at random, and used it for IO instead of the console, just because it was there. Find a socket tutorial, you need to accept connections after listening, and you need to read from the socket and write to it.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Are you saying i need to use certain type of print and raw input?

Comment: No, you need to actually read from the socket! `print` and `raw_input` read/write to `stdout` and `stdin`. See the [socket programming howto](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/sockets.html).

Comment: ^ can i have some example code to work with or no ?